# Converting XES to CSV with python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to convert XES eventlog files to CSV but I can't import factory from pm4py.
When I use the code:

```
from pm4py.objects.log.importer.xes import factory
log = xes_import_factory.apply("<path_to_xes_file>")
```

I get the error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'factory' from 'pm4py.objects.log.importer.xes' (C:\Users\Nutzer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pm4py\objects\log\importer\xes_*init*_.py)

I already installed pm4py on my terminal and I am not sure how I can correct the error.

Comment: Your import statement should look like this: `from pm4py.objects.log.importer.xes import factory as xes_import_factory` since you are later using `xes_import_factory`

Answer (score 2):

The simple, unparameterized way is:

```
log = pm4py.read_xes('log.xes.gz')
pd = pm4py.convert_to_dataframe(log)
```

The parameterized way:

```
from pm4py.objects.conversion.log import converter as xes_converter
from pm4py.objects.log.importer.xes import importer as xes_importer

log = xes_importer.apply('log.xes')
pd = xes_converter.apply(log, variant=xes_converter.Variants.TO_DATA_FRAME)
```

In most cases, the 'simple' invocation is enough.